# How to fix body there are sidebar inside. The Body is offset

Tags: bootstrap-4

I use sidebar for my website, but the content in body still cross the line. I use bootstrap framework and laravel framework

this is my code

```css
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
#sidebar{
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-height: 100vh; 
    background: #042954;
    color: #fafafa;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#content {
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class=" navbar navbar-light bg-alhikmah-primary navbar-alhikmah">
    </nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="sidebar"></nav>

        <div id="content">
            <main>
                @yield('content')
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</body
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzQwC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `calc` function to calculate the with of your content like this:

```
#content {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}
```

250px = the width of sidebar